# CreateDelegate of Nested Internal type

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to convert a method to an internal (and nested) delegate type. The problem is that because it's internal, `Delegate.CreateDelegate` fails and throws an exception.

`System.ArgumentException:` *Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.*

Here's the relevant code for how I'm trying to accomplish this.

```
// The method to convert to the internal delegate type
private void OnEnterMenuMode(object sender, EventArgs e);

// The internal nested delegate type
public sealed class KeyboardNavigation {
internal delegate bool EnterMenuModeEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

// The code used to create the delegate
object instance; // Owner of OnEnterMenuMode
EventInfo eventInfo; // The internal event
Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, instance,
    ((Action<object,EventArgs>)method).Method);
```

Comment: An `Action<T>` is for a `void` method, but the method you want to reference returns a `Boolean` (`bool`) value. That's why you're getting the error. It's nothing to do with it being a nested type.

Comment: Edit, I apologize. I copied an older version of the function declaration before I set it to `void` return. It still produces the same error.

Comment: If it hurts when you do that, then don't do that.  You're not supposed to be able to construct an object of a type that you don't have access to, so stop trying to do that, because it's the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @EricLippert I'm surprised to hear you say that, Reflection has many great uses for making workarounds for bugs in external code.

Comment: @Dai: If someone marked it as internal, that's because it's an *implementation detail of an assembly*, not part of the public surface.

Comment: It is a really bad idea to rely on 3rd party API internals. We blew up a platform once because somebody thought they'd get clever with reflection and use some of Microsoft's internal crypto functions, which got removed when we went from 4.0 to 4.5. To me, it is dirt obvious you ***do not rely on third party internals***

Comment: @EricLippert I have to wait two days to mark my own question as answered. If I could I would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution by constructing the Delegate through a `ConstructorInfo` and a function `IntPtr`.

```
object instance; // Owner of OnEnterMenuMode
EventInfo eventInfo; // The internal event
// There is only one constructor for a `Delegate`, so this
// just makes it easier to find without all of the arguments.
ConstructorInfo constructor = eventInfo.EventHandlerType.GetConstructors()[0];
// Delegate constructors take arguments of `(object, IntPtr)`.
// Where `IntPtr` is a pointer to the method.
IntPtr ptr = ((Action<object,EventArgs>)method)
    .Method.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();
return (Delegate) constructor.Invoke(new object[] { instance, ptr });
```